# How is Imagick::transformImage() suddenly "undefined"?

Tags: php, imagick

Recently my hoster updated Imagick to this version:
[image]

so this code that worked before:

```php
        $img = new \Imagick();
        $output &= $img->readImage($path_to_image);
        $img->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);

        $imageprops = $img->getImageGeometry();
        $width = $imageprops['width'];
        $height = $imageprops['height'];
        $img = $img->transformImage($width . "x" . $height, "200x");
```

is now throwing this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Imagick::transformImage()
```

which is puzzling me as the method does not look to be removed from Imagick: https://www.imagemagick.org/api/Magick++/classMagick_1_1transformImage.html#af49f28733ed10c66dfdfcdcb1321320b

What could be causing the method to be "undefined" in my case?

I'm running on PHP Version 5.6.40.

Comment: I don't know imagick very much although I have worked with it in the past, can only see that in your `$width . "x" . $height, "200x"` you have a comma after the `$height` but used a dot after `$width`, so  I am not sure if that would cause an issue or "the" issue. See the manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.transformimage.php just in case.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, the dots combine a string to form the first `$crop` argument (e.g. "640x480") and the comma separates that with the second `$geometry` argument (e.g. "200x") -- all according to the doc you have linked :)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but unrelated thought... Will there be a problem with reassigning `$img = $img->transformImage();`?